# Rails concern getting stuck in -cache-?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model `BusinessLog`:

```
class BusinessLog < ActiveRecord::Base
  include BusinessLogging
  default_scope { where(business_id: Business.current.id) }
end
```

it performs operations in a default scope and includes a concern `BusinessLog`:

```
class BusinessLog < ActiveRecord::Base
  module BusinessLogging
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    module ClassMethods
      def log!(options)
        create! business_id: options[:business_id], user_id: options[:user_id], action: options[:action]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

this `log!` method was being called by a `sidekiq` worker. Eventually I discovered I couldn't log for several business because of `BusinessLog` default scope. So I removed the `BusinessLog` default scope, but it was somehow stuck.

Whenever I tried to perform operations through the module (eg: `BusinessLog.log!(options)`), it was still working with a default scope (even thought I already removed it). But when I performed operations in the model itself (eg: `BusinessLog.create!(options)`), it was working as expected, without the -already gone- default scope.

I tried a lot of things to make it work, but only one thing worked: Renamed the module and everything worked perfectly again.

It's worth saying that this just happened on my production environment.

Has anyone been through this? Should I post it as an issue on github? How could I give more information about this -bug-?
I'm using Rails 4.0.1 and ruby 2.0.0

Comment: Have you restarted your server after making this change?

Comment: Did you restart your _Sidekiq_ workers?  If not, they may still be running with references to the old code base.

Comment: Yes, I did restart everything again, even the server, because this made no sense to me. Thanks for answering